# Way to count last values before each zero?

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the last value before it resets back to zero multiple times per column. Here is my example

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
1
0
0
1
2
3
0
```

And the list goes on but for this example I would be looking to do something like a LARGE or SMALL where I could get the answers like this:

```
8
6
1
3
```

Ultimately I would like them to be in the descending order, but if that isn't part of the formula I can take care of that if I can just figure out a way to capture them.

Can this be done?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following in column B try the following `=IF(A2=0,IF(A1=0,"";A1),"")`

then filter column B on non blank value

Answer (score 0):

Put your original data in column **B**

In cell **A2** enter:

=IF(AND(B2<>0, B3=0),MAX($A$1:A1)+1,"")

and copy down.  Finally in **C1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(),$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE)
```

and copy down till you see errors.  Should look like:

[image: pic]

Basically column **A** is a "helper" column used to mark all the "good" values to facilitate easy pick-up

Comment: Thank you.  It worked just as well, but the other one is one less step for my situation.  Wish I could give you both check marks!

Comment: That's O.K........the "helper" column approach may be useful to you some time in the future